# Firefox: wrong interpretation of box model?

Tags: firefox, css

I just discovered strange behaviour of Firefox.

If I have a table cell of 100px height, and add 20px padding to it - it's total height should become 140px.

All browsers act correctly, Firefox 8.0 ignores the padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/

Anyone knowing a fix?

Comment: In Firebug, it does compute the padding, but the computed height is `60px`.

Comment: Maybe some issues with the default styles of Firefox. Resetting the styles won't work too... (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: You mean with a CSS reset? Same result... http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/3/

Comment: One solution would be to wrap the contents of the cell in a DIV element and then set the height on that DIV instead of the table cell...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes, that's how I fixed it for now - I think it's the best future proof fix..

Comment: @ptriek: see my solution for probably a better "future proof fix."

Comment: @scott i've seen it, nice one, thanks. i did find a somewhat related bug in the bug tracker http://tinyurl.com/clde2yh - though i'm not sure about the meaning of content-box/border-box - so i don't know if it's the same issue...

Comment: It's the same issue, amazing that it's existed for six years.  You can find an explanation of content/border-box [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the best cross browser solution may be to set the full height of the table row equal to height and padding of the cell:

```
tr {height: 140px;}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/19/

Answer (score 3):

that is a strange behave. add `display:block;` can fix the problem. tested in `FF8.01` see:

http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/1/

But I also do not know why?

I searched in `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=table+padding`, but did not find anything. May be you can also try to search in there.

**UPDATE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/7/

add `overflow:hidden` to avoid the `td` change line.

Comment: It seems that the `td` tag has not set `display:block`. But it is a block element strange.

Comment: +1 for the inventivity - however - it only works for tables with one cell :-/ http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/4/

Comment: @rekire The default `display` value of table cells is `table-cell`.

Comment: You are right I forgot that. That works for me as well in more than one cell. (Firefox 8.0)

Comment: @rekire no, if i set the td to display:block, they are placed vertically instead of horizontally. i also tried inline-block, but as expected the td's jump to the next line if the width of the table is too small...

Comment: @ptriek, add `overflow:hidden` to avoid the td change line, see my update answer. and code in `http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/7/`

Comment: @ptriek, so what are u want? make 4 td horizontally in one line?

Comment: @ptriek, the table will adjust the `width, height` automatically. see  `http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/7/show/` if your screen width is enough, they will in one line. and now adjust your FF browser edge, make the screen narrow, the td will change line. this is why your  `skit.ch/nyay` have 2 line. if you want to force them in one line, you should give table a width. see `http://jsfiddle.net/8wDde/10/`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any information about this on Google, so one way to fix it for Firefox would be to use a CSS hack.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
td{
    height:140px !important;
}
}
```

Obviously, if the height was `200px`, then you'd change that to `240px` to account for the missing `20px` on top and on bottom.

That targets all Firefox versions, I'm not sure if theres a FF8 specific css hack.

You can see this demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/8wDde/2/

***Edit: I like Giberno's answer more***

Comment: If all else fails, play dirty ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Diagram of row, cell box and padding effect]

This is a fuller description of a couple of comments I made on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377523/css-table-display-differences-chrome-vs-firefox/8377666), hopefully a little bit clearer. Note that Opera has the same behaviour as Firefox.

In the diagram above, the total cell area is the dark box, and the text `My Text` is the content of the `td`, and it is that that defines the Cell Box (C).

Now, the CSS 2.1 spec says:

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user
>   agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the
>   row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the
>   row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells. A 'height'
>   value of 'auto' for a 'table-row' means the row height used for layout
>   is MIN. MIN depends on cell box heights and cell box alignment (much
>   like the calculation of a line box height). ...
>
> In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by
>   the content. The table cell's 'height' property can influence the
>   height of the row (see above), but it does not increase the height of
>   the cell box.

So `td { height:100px; }` affects the Row Height (R) (it will be at least 100px high) but does not effect the Cell Box (C).

On the other hand, `td { padding:20px; }` applies to the Cell Box (C), so if the height of (C) + Top Padding + Bottom Padding is less than 100px, the row height is not affected and is still 100px.

If (C) + Top Padding + Bottom Padding is greater that 100px, the row height will expand to accommodate the full height of (C) + Top Padding + Bottom Padding.

Then `td { background-color:blue }` applies to the full row height (R) and cell width.

You can see this in action at http://jsfiddle.net/Ez7xz/

The final confusing factor is the value of the computed height of the `td` in Firebug. What seems to be happening here is that it is assuming that the height is the result of `content-box` box sizing, and reporting the value of R less the top and bottom padding. While this seems odd, it's not obvious what other value it could reasonably report.