# Listview template doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, listview, templates, firefox

I've made a web form page with Listview. It's working properly in Chrome, but it doesn't in Firefox. I'm sure that it isn't CSS fault.
Any ideas why is it happening?

Code of my index page:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupItemCount="2" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); width: 405px; height: 200px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 10px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/news.aspx?id={0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("tytul", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="dataLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("data") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image", "{0}") %>' Height="100px" Width="100px" Visible='<%# Eval("image")!=DBNull.Value %>' style="float:left; margin-left:0px; margin-right: 5px;"/>
                <asp:Label ID="trescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tresc") %>' CssClass="contenttext"/>
                <br />
            </td>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="">ID:
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                <br />
                tytul:
                <asp:TextBox ID="tytulTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tytul") %>' />
                <br />tresc:
                <asp:TextBox ID="trescTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tresc") %>' />
                <br />data:
                <asp:TextBox ID="dataTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("data") %>' />
                <br />image:
                <asp:TextBox ID="imageTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("image") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                <br /></td>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table runat="server" style="">
                <tr>
                    <td>No data was returned.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <EmptyItemTemplate>
<td runat="server" />
        </EmptyItemTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
            </tr>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="">tytul:
                <asp:TextBox ID="tytulTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tytul") %>' />
                <br />tresc:
                <asp:TextBox ID="trescTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tresc") %>' />
                <br />data:
                <asp:TextBox ID="dataTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("data") %>' />
                <br />image:
                <asp:TextBox ID="imageTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("image") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                <br /></td>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); width: 405px; height: 200px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 10px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/news.aspx?id={0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("tytul", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="dataLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("data") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image", "{0}") %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" Visible='<%# Eval("image")!=DBNull.Value %>' style="float:left; margin-left:0px; margin-right: 5px;"/>
                <asp:Label ID="trescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tresc") %>' CssClass="contenttext" />
                </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server">
                        <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); width: 860px; height: 25px; display: block; margin: 0px 8px 0px 8px; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">
                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="4">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NumericPagerField />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="">ID:
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                <br />tytul:
                <asp:Label ID="tytulLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tytul") %>' />
                <br />tresc:
                <asp:Label ID="trescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tresc") %>' />
                <br />data:
                <asp:Label ID="dataLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("data") %>' />
                <br />image:
                <asp:Label ID="imageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("image") %>' />
                <br />
            </td>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

View in Chrome (proper):
[image]

View in Firefox:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final HTML rendered by the Asp.Net server and thus sent to ANY browser will be same.

Probably the difference in layout/display here is because of the way different browsers interpret the same HTML.

With the use of Table here in your `<LayoutTemplate>`, Firefox is know to have some strange behaviors , especially with Padding.

Check this post: [**`Table Differences: Chrome vs Firefox`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377523/css-table-display-differences-chrome-vs-firefox)

As a last note, Avoid using tables for Layout. They aren't good anymore for SEO purpose besides reducing accessiblity and a number of other factors. Check this [**`Link`**](https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html).

Comment: Thanks for those links, they're really helpfull. Cheers!

Comment: Just change td tags to div tags inside AlternatingItemTemplate and ItemTemplate. Everything worked fine.