# So which of these browsers correctly interprets CSS Box Model, Firefox, IE or Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, css

Padding is never the same in Firefox and IE, while IE adds padding to the height and width, Firefox just ignores it. what is the correct interpretation and what is the nest way to achieve the same look in all the browsers. Does firefox and Ie differ in margin a well?

Comment: Can you provide a sample on, say, http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: "So which of these guys correctly interprets CSS Box Model, Firefox, IE or Chrome" I'm sure all of them do (for sufficiently recent versions of IE).

Comment: You are describing an issue that affected IE 5 and earlier...

Comment: I am talking i general e-g:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370008/firefox-wrong-interpretation-of-box-model
BoltClock congrats for the promotion. I voted for you

Comment: @Mike - you will always find bugs in one browser or another in certain edge cases.  That just happens in software.  You can only deal with this on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to ensure the different *defaults* the different browsers have chosen are neutralized.

The differences you see are due to different default values for margin and padding that each browser has for different elements.

One additional wrinkle is that some browsers require some content to be in a container (say table cell or div) before applying width/height to it. This can easily be done by adding a non-break-space - `&nbsp;`.

Comment: After adding this, will firefox add the css heights and widths

Comment: @Mike - Which css heights and widths? You didn't show any HTML or CSS.

Comment: I am saying in general. padding is neber the same for ie and ff e-g
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370008/firefox-wrong-interpretation-of-box-model

Comment: @Mike - In practice, yes, padding is always the same for ie and ff, with the exception of a few edge case bugs in different versions of browsers.

Answer (score 5):

In modern browsers, you can use the [`box-sizing` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing) to instruct the browser about the exact box model you want. If such property is missing, all browsers built since year 2000 (aprox.) will default to the good old [W3c box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). In such model, neither margin nor padding are part of the content dimensions (width and height), as [this figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box_model) illustrates.

In practice, I'd dare say that 99% of web sites rely on the latter, and the rest are legacy sites that were designed for Netscape and Internet Explorer 4 and have been abandoned since then.

If you need to support very old versions of Internet Explorer, make sure you have valid HTML with an appropriate DOCTYPE. Otherwise, IE will render under quirks mode and might revert to old box sizing model.

Comment: I agree with Mike: +1 from me too

Answer (score 1):

All browsers from the last 10 years render the box model correctly *IF* you are not running in compatibility or quirks mode.  That means you have to have a valid doctype, it must be on the first line (anything before the doctype throws IE into quirksmode) and you can't do illegal things that also throw it into quicksmode.

If you have valid content, with a valid doctype, content will render the same.. although different browsers may have different default values for some styles, which is where a good html reset file comes in handy.  This levels the playing field so all browsers have the same default styles.